# How to print each element of an array in new line in txt file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, writefile

My result set is an array that returns from a function.

```
['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5','item6','item7','item8']
```

I am writing it into a file using

```
fs.writeFile('out.txt', uniqueMatches, (err)=>{
     if(err) throw err;
          console.log('Extract saved successful');
});
```

I see the out.txt as

```
item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6, item7,item8
```

How do I print them as?

```
item1
item2
item3
item4
item5
item6
item7
item8
```

Comment: is `uniqueMatches`  your array?

Comment: Maybe `uniqueMatches.join("\n")`

Comment: Check out `Array.join`. Just join the items with `\n`, and you should be good.

Comment: have you tried to iterate your uniqueMatches array construct a string where you append "\r\n" to the end of each item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `join()` to add the new lines :

```
fs.writeFile('out.txt',
    uniqueMatches.join('\n'),
    function (err) { console.log('Extract saved successful'); }
);
```

Comment: May I ask why you called map, uniqueMatches sould already be a array so whats the point?

Comment: Thanks for your intevention @dotoconnor I just forgot it there

Comment: Glad I could help brother. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to add a line break to your data array that is to be written:

```
fs.writeFile('out.txt', uniqueMatches.join('\n');, (err)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log('Extract saved successful');
        });
```