# Write an array into an file fs

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to create a .txt file which contains my array, using fs.

My array looks like this:

```
const array = [1111, 2222, 33333]
```

The code below allows me to write in the file and seperate each entry with a comma but I cant get them on a new line. Neither using `\n` nor `\r\n`

```
await fs.writeFile('Participants.txt', `${array}, \r\n`);
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: see: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: What is `eligible`? Should that be `array`?

Comment: @Barmar sry you are right my bad. Corrected it

Comment: @pilchard I have read somewhere that this can cause problems with bigger arrays

Comment: You indicate that you have an array with three elements in it.

Comment: Duplicate: [How to print each element of an array in new line in txt file using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52190559/how-to-print-each-element-of-an-array-in-new-line-in-txt-file-using-javascript)

Comment: also: [node.js - how to write an array to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614123/node-js-how-to-write-an-array-to-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

```
const array = [1111, 2222, 33333]
var arrayLength = array.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    fs.appendFile('Participants.txt', `${array[i]}\n`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `array.join()`:

```
const text_string = eligible.join('\n');

await fs.writeFile('Participants.txt', text_string);
```

In the example above I separated out the string you want to write to the file into a variable for clarity so that it is obvious what's going on. Of course you could skip the extra variable and just do `eligible.join('\n')` directly in the `fs.writeFile()` but I wanted to make it clear that this feature has nothing to do with `fs` nor any string syntax nor any function argument syntax. It is simply a feature of Arrays.

Comment: You may also be interested in the opposite of `.join()` which is `.split()`. While `.join()` merges an array into a string `.split()` breaks up a string into an array.